# React Native how to make border to the corner of the square only like QR code marker

Tags: react-native, border, qr-code, react-native-stylesheet

I was trying to make a QR code marker like this pic below.

[image]

So I'm wondering how to make those 4 corners instead of a full border marker.

I was currently using [react-native-qrcode-scanner](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner).

The default marker is like this:

[image]

and here is the code that I have:

```
<QRCodeScanner
        // containerStyle={{ height: '100%' }}
        // cameraStyle={{ height: '100%' }}
        onRead={handleScan}
        showMarker
        markerStyle={{ borderColor: colors.primary, borderRadius: 20 }}
        cameraProps={{
          captureAudio: false,
          flashMode: RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto,
        }}
```

But I want to change it to the first image I gave.

Appreciate it if someone could help.
Thanks

Comment: hello, I am sorry bother you. I also have a problem like you. Do you solve this problem. If you ok, can you share the code. I read the doc but I am no experience React native. I hope you share the code . If you agree my suppose. can you send me the code.My email glistenstar00@gmail.com. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it would have been a straight line, it would have been easy by putting border radius. But since its bit different , you can achieve this by using this library :

[RN-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) , where you can provide the xml pattern and it will render acordingly, just you need to position beside the marker, that's it.

Hopeit helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: can your provide a working code ... will be much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

`QRCodeScanner` has a `customMarker` prop which allows you to use any `JSX.Element` as marker.

Here is what I am currently using myself:

```
function marker(color: string, size: string | number, borderLength: string | number, thickness: number = 2, borderRadius: number = 0): JSX.Element {
  return <View style={{ height: size, width: size }}>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: borderLength, width: borderLength, top: 0, left: 0, borderColor: color, borderTopWidth: thickness, borderLeftWidth: thickness, borderTopLeftRadius: borderRadius }}></View>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: borderLength, width: borderLength, top: 0, right: 0, borderColor: color, borderTopWidth: thickness, borderRightWidth: thickness, borderTopRightRadius: borderRadius }}></View>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: borderLength, width: borderLength, bottom: 0, left: 0, borderColor: color, borderBottomWidth: thickness, borderLeftWidth: thickness, borderBottomLeftRadius: borderRadius }}></View>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: borderLength, width: borderLength, bottom: 0, right: 0, borderColor: color, borderBottomWidth: thickness, borderRightWidth: thickness, borderBottomRightRadius: borderRadius }}></View>
  </View>
}
```

Which, in your case could be used like this:

```
  <QRCodeScanner
    ...
    customMarker={marker('white', '60%', '25%', 6, 20)}
  />
```

[image: How it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have recently used:

```
<BarCodeScanner
            onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
          />
        </View>
       <View style={[styles.border,
       {
        width: qrCodeDimensions.width || 250,
        height: qrCodeDimensions.height || 250, 
      },
      ]}>
       <View style={[styles.corner, styles.topLeft]} />
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.topRight]} />
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.bottomLeft]} />
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.bottomRight]} />
       </View>

       <View style={styles.tap}>
          {scanned && (
        <Button 
        title='Tap to Scan Again' onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />
      )}
```

//style:
frameContainer: {
position: 'relative',
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',

```
  },

  corner: {
    width: 30, // Adjust the width of the corner dashes
    height: 30, // Adjust the height of the corner dashes
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: color.primary,
    position: 'absolute',
    borderRadius: 2
  },
  topLeft: {
    top: -1,
    left: -1,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  topRight: {
    top: -1,
    right: -1,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  bottomLeft: {
    bottom: -1,
    left: -1,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
  },
  bottomRight: {
    bottom: -2,
    right: -1,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
  },
  border: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    position: 'relative',
  },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).